# Generating and populating an XML file based off an XSD schema in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Looking for some advice on a tool that I am attempting to create, as I have little to no knowledge on XML.

The scenario is that I have an XSD schema; I have generated a C# class using the XSD tool in the Visual studio command line.

I have then created a basic console app, which will populate the first partial class in the generated C# class.

The program will then serialize this data and create an XML in a folder as a proof of concept.

The issue I’m having is working out the best way to populate and serialize all the data from the class, as the XSD it was generated from is quite large.

Any advice on the best way to handle this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to iterate over the members of your class and populate them with default values depending on the type of the members.

Then serialize and hope like hell that your XML will validate against the schema.

The reason I say this is that inferring .cs from XSD is not an exact science, in that it doesn't guarantee that the XML thus produced by serialization will comply.